# Poset where no infinite descending chain has a lower bound

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, forcing

Suppose $(\mathbb{P},\leq)$ is a partial order that is (i) separative, i.e. if $x\nleq y$ then $\exists ~z\leq x$ s.t. no $w$ satisfies $w\leq z$ and $w\leq y$ (ii) every strictly descending chain does *not* have a lower bound (so this is the exact opposite of $\sigma$-closedness). Can we say anything about the structure of $\mathbb{P}$? Does it contain a tree of height $\omega$ as a dense subset? A naive attempt is to take a maximal antichain $A_0$, and a maximal antichain $A_1$ strictly below $A_0$, etc. But I couldn't show that $\bigcup_i A_i$ is dense.

Comment: Any maximal anticahin is dense on its own, so I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Isn't a maximal antichain pre-dense rather than dense?

Comment: Ah, yes, I often conflate the two. (BTW I didn't downvote.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $X$ infinite and $|Y| \geq 2$, define $Fn(X, Y)$ to be the set of all finite partial functions from $X$ to $Y$ ordered by $p \leq q \iff q \subseteq p$. All of these satisfy

($\star$) No strictly descending sequence of conditions has a lower bound.

If $|Y| \leq \omega < |X|$, then $Fn(X, Y)$ is ccc forcing of uncountable density ($ = |X|$) and hence a countable union of antichains in $Fn(X, Y)$ cannot be dense. There is no upper limit on either the chain-condition (increase $|Y|$) or the density (increase $|X|$) of these posets. Moreover, every separative sub-poset of these posets also satisfies $(\star)$. So I doubt that there is a useful characterization for this class.

Comment: Then can ($\star$) be characterized as (essentially) sub-poset of $Fn(X,Y)$?

Comment: No. All subposets of $Fn(X, Y)$ have the finite predecessor property (Every condition extends only finitely many conditions). Consider random forcing $\mathbb{B}$ with ordering modified to $p \leq q$ iff $p \setminus q$ is null and $\mu(p) \leq 0.5 \mu(q)$. Then $\mathbb{B}$ satisfies $(\star)$. It cannot be isomorphic to a subposet of $Fn(X, Y)$ because it doesn't have the finite predecessor property.